# Dart Mocking HTML library

Tags: mocking, dart

I have a Dart class I would like to unit test and I would like to mock the calls to the dart:html library to ensure that my class is behaving as expected.  I have looked at the article for [Mocking with Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/mocking-with-dart/) but it does't mention how to mock the HTML libraries.  Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: dart:html also contains non-UI classes like, localStorage and sessionStorage, which are the basis for client persistance.  I want make ensure my data storage and load routines work and don't regress.  I want to mock the Storage class, but cannot beause, to mock it I must import dart:html in my unit test file.  But Dart's pub system won't allow that.  Instead it gives the error: "Do not know how to load 'dart:html'".  Is there a way to mock classes from dart:html without importing dart:html (in a unit test)?

Answer (score 1):

This is not easily doable as **dart:html** library is not headless (i.e. it needs a browser). I usually try to follow the MVP design pattern to make sure that the code that interacts with the DOM is only in my view class and that all biz logic is in the presenter. That way I unit test the presenter without needing access to DOM API's. A small example is included below.

```
// view interface has no reference to dart:html
abstract class View {
   hello();
}

// view impl uses dart:html but hands of all logic to the presenter
class ViewImpl implements View {
   View(this._presenter) {
      var link = new Element.html("<a href="">a link</a>");
      link.on.click.add(_presenter.onClick());
      body.nodes.add(link);
   }

   hello() {
      body.nodes.add(new Element.html("<p>Hello from presenter</p>");
   }

   Presenter _presenter;
}

// presenter acts on the View interface and can therefor be tested with a mock.
class Presenter {
  Presenter(this._view);

  onClick() => _view.hello();

  View _view;
}
```